# Django template datetime format in for loop - invisible

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-templates

Model:

```
...
date_end = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Finish date and time", default=None, null=True, blank=True)
...
```

Template:

```
{% for result in results %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/test/result/{{ result.id }}/">{{ result.title }}</a></td>
        <td>{{result.date_end}}</td>
        <td>{{ result.percents }}%</td>
        <td><a href="/test/result/{{ result.id }}/">
            <button style="width:50px; height:30px;
            background-image:url({{STATIC_URL}}/css/images/eye46.png);
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            border-radius: 6px;
            background-position: 50% 50%;" title="Show result"></button>
        </a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Result:

[image]

If I use date format (i.e "M d, Y"):

```
 ...
 <td>{{result.date_end|date:"M d, Y"}}</td>
 ...
```

date is not displayed:

[image]

What is the problem?

**UPDATE:**

If I use variable not from "for loop" filter is worked and date displayed:

```
...
<td>{{my_value|date:"M d, Y"}}</td>
...
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any custom template filter that also called "date"?

Comment: ShangWang, I did not add custom template filters, 
but I don't know how to check them out in the project?

Comment: You could check the page see if there's any `{% load xyz %}` statement. Those "xyz"s are the files defined custom filter/template tags.

Comment: check your settings.py and see if you DATE_FORMAT or USE_L10N there ??

Comment: I don't find "DATE_FORMAT" or "USE_L10N" in settings. Problem in "for loop" (See UPDATE).